# Raspberry communication with multiple Arduino's over long distance wire

Tags: tcp, arduino, raspberry-pi, embedded, i2c

Recently i was digging information about communication between RaspberryPi and multiple Arduino slaves over long distance wire (10-15 meters). My initial thought was to use I2C, but after doing some research i have found out that wire length is a problem since it does not capable to transit/receive data over such a distance. Maybe someone would have any suggestions?

I was thinking about another approach - communication over ethernet (using shields). I would place a switch between all the Arduino nodes and Raspberry with multi threaded TCP server on RPI. Does it sound reasonable?

P.S. Wireless communication methods are not allowed.

Comment: Initially at least this is a hardware/electronics question so off-topic here: try at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Clifford thank you. I will try to ask there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one of many standards for communications, such as [RS-485](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) or [CAN-bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus). Both of those allow for "long" distances, but the longer the wire, the slower the speed.

You will need transceivers for each device, but you can buy pre-made modules for quite cheap.

Comment: CAN-bus is too expensive for this project since modules cost a bit. I have tried RS-485 but i think it does not fit my requirements. RS-485 uses master-slave logic and you need to control the data flow.
For example at the same time one of the slave devices will try to communicate with master and the master at the same time will be communicating with another slave.

Comment: @ArnArm You suggested Ethernet, which taking into account the switch and the Arduino modules, should be more expensive than CAN. IIRC, CAN modules are around 1.5 USD, and Ethernet modules are around 3 USD.